# Swipe to delete

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, swipe, delete-row

I Have a tableview and a cell in it :D with disclosure accessory selected. I created all ui elements with storyboard. 
(didn't put a view in  content of the cell)
I'm using SWTableViewCell to implement just swipe-to-delete, but everything seems work fine except when i put a breakpoint on to a method

```
#pragma mark -SWTableViewDelegate-

-(void)swipeableTableViewCell:(SWTableViewCell *)cell didTriggerRightUtilityButtonWithIndex:(NSInteger)index
{

    NSIndexPath *path=[self.table indexPathForCell:cell];
    [anArray removeObjectAtIndex:path.row];
    [self.table deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[path] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
}
```

and this will help you to understand what i simply done here

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    SWTableViewCell *cell=(SWTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (!cell)
    {

        NSMutableArray *rightUtilityButtons = [NSMutableArray new];
        [rightUtilityButtons sw_addUtilityButtonWithColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f
                                                                      green:0.231f
                                                                       blue:0.188
                                                                      alpha:1.0f]
    title:@"Delete"];

        cell = [[SWTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell" containingTableView:_table leftUtilityButtons:nil rightUtilityButtons:rightUtilityButtons];
    }

    NSMutableDictionary *deDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[anArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    cell.textLabel.text= [deDict objectForKey:@"Name"];

    return cell;
}
```

Yet, I don't get any error, because when i try to swipe on simulator, it simply does not work..

Answer (score 0):

No need to use SWTableViewCell just Override following built-in methods of UITableView delegate for support conditional editing & swipe to delete

for conditional editing **-- Optional --**

```
//Override this method only if you are going to be returning NO for some items. 
//By default, all items are editable.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return YES if you want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
```

**for swipe to delete**

```
// Override to support editing the table view.
// for swipe to delete
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        //add code here for when you hit delete
    }    
}
```

Comment: They are not `UITableView` methods and you don't override them. They are delegate methods.

Comment: well I'm doing commitEdittingStyle and titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath right now,to  see that works

Comment: then it's ok no need to worry about it just swipe from right to left and you see delete button and it perform action as per commitEdittingStyle when it pressed

Comment: if this helpful to find your solution then accept my Ans & don't forgot to Up

Comment: well the problem is, i assigned delegate on storyboard, not did it programmatically

Comment: because other staffs need its delegate are just doing fine

Comment: Is that because I selected disclosure button on storyboard?

Comment: i can't getting your above three comments so please describe it with all details or show code related to that in your que.

Comment: don't need to take cell of type SWTableViewCell just take cell of type UITableViewCell. so, you have no need to delegate that cell And delete button comes automatically